# Error has occurred: Wait on the DataBase Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I spent several hours, however I can't find the solution for this issue.

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893606
  Start time:                    2018-03-07 08:53:49
  End time:                      2018-03-07 10:10:05
  Requested action:              CompleteFailoverCluster

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, run RemoveNode on all the nodes of this instance, and then run PrepareFailoverCluster and then run CompleteFailoverCluster process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, run RemoveNode on all the nodes of this instance, and then run PrepareFailoverCluster and then run CompleteFailoverCluster process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, run RemoveNode on all the nodes of this instance, and then run PrepareFailoverCluster and then run CompleteFailoverCluster process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, run RemoveNode on all the nodes of this instance, and then run PrepareFailoverCluster and then run CompleteFailoverCluster process again.


Cluster properties:
  Machine name: SQL-SERV-1
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.0.2000.8     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality Services                    1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       

  Machine name: SQL-SERV-2
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  SQL-SERV-1
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  Yes

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.0.2000.8     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality Services                    1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         E:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Enterprise

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        CompleteFailoverCluster
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180307_085348\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CONFIRMIPDEPENDENCYCHANGE:     false
  ENU:                           true
  FAILOVERCLUSTERDISKS:          Cluster Disk 1
  FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
  FAILOVERCLUSTERIPADDRESSES:    IPv4;192.168.10.29;Cluster Network 1;255.255.254.0
  FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    SQLNET2
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             S:\
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  SAPWD:                         
  SECURITYMODE:                  
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           MYCOSMETIC\sqlagent, MYCOSMETIC\Administrator
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180307_085348\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, run RemoveNode on all the nodes of this instance, and then run PrepareFailoverCluster and then run CompleteFailoverCluster process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026


  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup error log you've included in your question states the following as the next steps needed to resolve the problem:

```
run RemoveNode on all the nodes of this instance, and then run PrepareFailoverCluster 
and then run CompleteFailoverCluster process again.
```

Have you done that?

Also, this error:

```
Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the 
SQL Server error log for potential causes.
```

is referring to the [SQL Server Engine Error Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log) - it might be helpful to look at that for items that need attention.